# CDI: Annotation to exclude class from scanning

Tags: cdi, noclassdeffounderror, weld

I have a class which is only used optionally, loaded dynamically, when some other dependency is available.

But CDI (Weld) scans it and reports an ugly error, see below.

How can I get rid of it, ideally using some annotation?

```
Registered contexts: [interface javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped, interface javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped, interface javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped, interface javax.enterprise.context.Dependent, interface javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped, interface javax.inject.Singleton]
Registered beans: 0
: [<class>org.jboss.weld.environment.se.jpa.JpaTransactionInterceptor</class> in jar:file:/home/ondra/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jawabot/JawaBot-core/2.0.0.GA-SNAPSHOT/JawaBot-core-2.0.0.GA-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml@11]
10:45:12.713 INFO  [main] org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading  WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.jawabot.plugin.jira.tools.ProjectsListDownloader because of underlying class loading error
10:45:12.714 INFO  [main] org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading  catching
org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONException
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.discovery.url.WeldSEResourceLoader.classForName(WeldSEResourceLoader.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadClass(BeanDeployer.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.ForwardingBootstrap.deployBeans(ForwardingBootstrap.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:133)
    at org.jboss.jawabot.JawaBotApp.main(JawaBotApp.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.discovery.url.WeldSEResourceLoader.classForName(WeldSEResourceLoader.java:54)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 12 more
10:45:12.931 WARN  [main] org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry  Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
10:45:12.931 WARN  [main] org.jboss.weld.interceptor.util.InterceptionTypeRegistry  Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
10:45:12.955 DEBUG [main] org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap  WELD-000108 Decorator: Decorator [class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.threading.RunnableDecorator] decorates [Runnable] with delegate type [Runnable] and delegate qualifiers [@Default]
10:45:12.956 DEBUG [main] org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap  WELD-000107 Interceptor: Interceptor [class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.jpa.JpaTransactionInterceptor intercepts @JpaTransactional]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no annotation to do that out of the box, but Apache Deltaspike and several others provide `@Veto`.

Instead of adding a dependency you could just make a simple CDI extension that will veto your type, something like this:

```
public class VetoExtension implements Extension {

    public void vetoMyType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<YourTypeGoesHere> pat) {
        pat.veto();
    }

}
```

You can see this for more into and a specific example: [CDI Portable Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html)

As per @LightGuard's comment below, in CDI 1.1 this will be available out of the box with `@Vetoed`

Comment: Right, I looked at @Vetoed, but my app didn't work with Weld 2.x, maybe I'll look into it, fix and use that.